# How to Add/Import/Insert new products to Volusion using Volusion API in PHP with cURL

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, volusion

Could you help me to understand how to add new products to Volusion using the Volusion API in PHP with something like cURL?

Any useful links will be appreciated.

Comment: are you using the api ?

Comment: I am not using right now but on volusion site it seems that they have an api for this.
But there is not the sufficient info for implementiation

Comment: have you solved your issue ?

Comment: not yet, 
if you have some good solution please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make XML file in the format like this with name "myXML.txt".

```html
<Import>
   <Products>
      <ProductID>360</ProductID>
      <productcode>10035</productcode>
      <vendor_partno>035</vendor_partno>
      <productname>Asus Video Card ATI Doulat</productname>
      <listprice>6.95</listprice>
      <productprice>2</productprice>
      <vendor_price>3.83</vendor_price>
      <stockstatus>100</stockstatus>
      <upc_code>99999</upc_code>
      <categoryids>107,134</categoryids>
      <productdescriptionshort />
      <productdescription />
      <productweight>0.00</productweight>
      <freeshippingitem />
      <minqty />
      <maxqty />
   </Products>
</Import>
```

2. Then copy and paste this in your editor

```html
<?php

    $file = file_get_contents('myXML.txt', true);

//  Create the Xml to POST to the Webservice

    $Xml_to_Send = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "<Volusion_API>";
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "<!--";
    $Xml_to_Send .= $file;
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "\"\"";
//  $Xml_to_Send .= "-->";
    $Xml_to_Send .= "</Volusion_API>";

    $url = "https://www.xxxxxusa.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=xxxx@xxxxxxxcom.com&EncryptedPassword=0000000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxxxx&Import=Update";

//  Create the Header   

    $header  = array(
    "MIME-Version: 1.0",
    "Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-transfer-encoding: text",
    "Request-number: 1",
    "Document-type: Request",
    "Interface-Version: Test 1.4"
);

    //  Post and Return Xml
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Xml_to_Send); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    //  Check for Errors
    if (curl_errno($ch)){
        print curl_error($ch);
    } else {
       curl_close($ch);
    }

   //  Display the Xml Returned on the Browser
    echo $data;
?>
```

Remember this use your own API credential. Try this hope you got the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your attention I will definitely try this :)

Comment: I have got the following error


False One or more of the following elements in your XML file is invalid: Import. The most likely reason is that you have embedded HTML tags or invalid characters (e.g., ampersands), and have not enclosed the elements in CDATA tags. For more information, please see any XML reference. 1


even in xml we do not have any '&' sign

Comment: Can you post your error in comment?? you just post i will correct it for future help.

Comment: i have resolved the error.
posted above with Using CDATA and Removing Volusion_API keyword and doing some refactoring in xml data 
thanks.

Comment: can u share your XML

Comment: here is my XML which is working fine
https://codepad.co/snippet/zFDWWxuy

Comment: One of friend says that my products are inserted but not show on the store front end.

Comment: I think Product is there in store but he is unable to find them 
He can download the products excel sheet and then find the product code there as it will be easy to find something in excel sheet.

Comment: no no bro the products are not shows on the front end of the store when he search his products. when i try thats true that products are inserted but when i search on my front store search i cant fine. i m working on it.

Comment: Actually volusoin search criteria is not as much good therefor I was asking to use excel sheet. Anyhow Good luck.

Comment: excel means?? any how i m trying to find the way for him

Comment: Is it possible to pass more than one products xml file bcoz one person raised this issue.